# How to smoothly interpolate between wave amplitudes?

Tags: trigonometry

I apologize if this is the incorrect place to ask, but I have a moving sine wave thats amplitude is determined by some frequency value. The problem is that the frequency can change pretty dramatically between frames, but instead of drawing the sine wave at amplitude $0$, then $100$, then $20$, etc. (wild fluctuations between frequency frames), I want a more smooth transition so that the line is not so "jumpy". Currently, the sine wave is calculated as:
$$\lambda \cdot \sin(5 \cdot(x_c + t)),$$
where $\lambda$ is the frequency, $x_c$ is the x-coordinate, and $t$ is time.

To clarify, the problem is that $\lambda$ fluctuates between values too rapidly.

Alternatively, I am certainly open to other ways of drawing waves based on $\lambda$ (not necessary only a sine wave).

Comment: So the "frequency" you're referring to is actually the amplitude of the sine wave; it doesn't have anything to do with frequency (within the question itself)?

Comment: The trivial answer is "linearly interpolate between values of lambda" but if you're asking this question I'm assuming you already tried that.